# Triple Nested For-loop with two independent outer loops and one dependent inner loop

Tags: algorithm

I have the following sequence of loops.

```
  TripleLoop(int n)
   for i <- 1 to n
       for j <- 1 to n
          for k <- j to n 
   do num <- j + i
   return num
```

I know the two outer loops run "n" times.
Thus, we have n * n = n^2 for the two outer loops.
However, the third inner loop depends on the variable "j".

How do I begin to solve these types of nested dependent for-loops?
I'm not sure if I should multiply, or add the third inner loop to the two outer loops.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I am having trouble calculating the run time for the inner for loop because it depends on the index j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the inner loop (the one with `k` as iterator) is executed `n-j+1` times, since it starts at `j` and ends with `n`.

The total number of *steps* the middle `for` loop thus performs is the sum of steps per iteration for `j`, so that means that the total number of times we run the body of the inner for loop is:

```
 n
---
\                  n * (n + 1)
/    n - j + 1  = -------------
---                    2
j=1
```

so after one iteration of the outer loop (the one with `i` as an iterator), we have `n*(n+1)/2` steps.

In total, our algorithm will thus run the body of the inner loop for a total of `n * n * (n+1)/2` times. Since the outer loop runs `n` times, and the number of steps in the body of that loop does *not* depend on the value of `i` itself.

If we consider the `num <- j + 1` part to run in constant time (well strictly speaking summing up huge numbers can not be done in constant time), then this is thus an *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* algorithm.

Comment: So, why is it O(n^3) if the inner loop depends on the index j. I thought that all for loops had to run from 1 to n in order for the entire algorithm to be O(n^3).

Comment: @JohnDoeX: because as specified in the answer, the sum of `n-j+1` with `j` from `1` to `n`, is `n*(n+1)/2`, which is of course an *O(n^2)*. Mind that *O(n^2)* is a *set of functions*. The number of steps is not *n^3*, that is *n^2*(n+1)/2*, but for time complexity that does not matter.